# I need to round a value up in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, math

I,m developing a debt calculation program 'my problem is when i have to calculate the months to pay back the debt it comes to 28.04 and i have to get it to 29 can some one pls help me out. 
Thank you in advance

my code looks like this:

```
    Dim b, SubMtP As Integer
    Dim outsUm, si

    outsUm = TextBox1.Text

    SubMtP = Format(Val(TextBox1.Text) / Val(TextBox2.Text), "0.00")
    Math.Round(SubMtP + 1)
    TextBox5.Text = Format(Val(TextBox4.Text) / 12, "0.00")

    For i As Integer = 1 To SubMtP
```

Comment: You call `Math.Round`, but you do not assign the return value to a variable, or otherwise use it. The result is that rounded value is immediately discarded. What are you actually trying to do there?

Answer (score 5):

Use `Math.Ceiling`.

Answer (score 2):

As Pavel said in the comment, you need to assign the result, and you should use `Ceiling`:

```
Dim result As Double = Math.Ceiling(SubMtP)
```

You are also **strongly** encouraged to switch `Option Strict On` everywhere in your code to enable strict, static type checking. This will result in a few compile errors in your above code that will need to be cleaned up. This is *good* because these code fragments are potential errors in your code and make it hard to maintain and to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
Math.Round(SubMtP + 1)
```

does not do anything (has no side effects) since you aren't assinging or otherwise using the result.

If you are trying to get from 28.04 to 29 then you probably want [`Math.Ceiling`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.ceiling.aspx). It's hard to tell what you are trying to do, but you probably want

```
SubMtP = Math.Ceiling(SubMtP);
```